# How to query nested object in Firestore?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore document with some fields and nested fields.

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "user": {
        "id": "ABC"
    }
}
```

How do I query by `"user.id"` in Objective-C? I tried this but it doesn't return any documents.

```
FIRQuery *collectionQuery = [collection queryWhereField:@"user.id" isEqualTo:"ABC"];
[collectionQuery getDocumentsWithCompletion:^(FIRQuerySnapshot * _Nullable snapshot, NSError * _Nullable error) {

}];
```

This works fine for reading the first level `"id"` field but I'm not able to read nested fields in the document.

```
FIRQuery *collectionQuery = [collection queryWhereField:@"id" isEqualTo:"123"];
[collectionQuery getDocumentsWithCompletion:^(FIRQuerySnapshot * _Nullable snapshot, NSError * _Nullable error) {

}];
```

Comment: We can't see how you built `collection`, nor can we see the specific data in your database that should match the query.  There could be any number of things going wrong here that are invisible in this question.  Please edit the question to show the [complete, minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code that reproduces the issue, and be clear about the contents of the database.

Comment: You also need to ensure you're authenticated before trying to read data.

Comment: I can read data fine it's just when I try to query a nested object.

Comment: I added another example to show that I can query first level fields fine. I'm just not sure what the syntax is for nested fields.

Comment: Why was my question closed?

Comment: Not the closer but it may have been closed because it's kinda vague. *some fields and nested fields* - what are 'nested fields'? Are they maps? Also, what's your collection actually look like? Is that at the top level? If you can clarify what's your asking and what you're after, we may be able to answer.